# Como fazer refresh na tabela sem atualizar toda a página?

Tags: php, tabela-html

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em PHP, e coloquei alguns botões para ativar e excluir a linha mas a mesma só retorna o resultado se eu atualizar toda a página, queria algo mais dinâmico na tabela.

Comment: Você precisa usar AJAX para fazer isso. Primeiro você vai capturar o evento do clique no botão, faz o request com o ajax e após o sucesso, modifica a parte da tabela. Tudo isso com Javascript. Para facilitar, eu recomendo usar o jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Sim tem como fazer refresh, é trocar html para utilizar jquery com ajax de carregar `$.get` ou `$.ajax` e veja o exemplo lucas de link.

Comment: Sugiro que você use um componente para isso. Recomendo o DataTable jquery. Olhe os links: http://www.devmedia.com.br/jquery-datatable-configurando-e-utilizando-o-plugin-em-php/28560 https://datatables.net

Comment: Ou se não quiser usar JavaScript podes sempre fazer o refresh de toda a página automaticamente.

Comment: Obrigado pessoal, estava bitolado no php e nem tinha tentado jquery, estou lendo a documentação...